# PowerShell to query SQL database with a string from a filename

Tags: sql, file, powershell

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that will check a folder for any files and then for every file it will grab part of the filename and check it against the SQL database.

If it found a match, it will rename the file and move it to another location.
If it did not find a match, then it will move the file to another location and send an email.

While the below script seems to work, I don't think it is written very well and it is definitely not error-proof.

Could I please ask the community to take a look and advise how the script could be improved?

Filename example: 8000000^Surname^Forenames^PERPDF^^20220111^^GEN^GB_PER___INI_20220111_041358.pdf

````
param (
    $logPath = "U:\x\Logs\$(Get-Date -format yyyy)\$(Get-Date -format MM)",
    $logName = "Verification_$(Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd).log",
    $localPath = "U:\x\00_Downloaded_Files\",
    $finalPath = "U:\x\01_Verification_Passed\",
    $errorsPath = "U:\x\03_Verification_Failed\",
    $SMTPServer = "gateway.domain.com",
    $EmailFrom = "$env:computername@domain.com",
    $EmailTo = "rudixx@domain.com",
    $EmailSubject = "Veryfication failed",
    $EmailAttachment = "$logPath\$logName",
    $EmailBody = "Veryfication failed.`r`nLog file attached."
)
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Recurse -Name

foreach ($File in $Files)
{

$EmployeeID = $File.Split("^")[0]
$Forenames = $File.Split("^")[2]
$Surname = $File.Split("^")[1]


Write-Host "EmployeeID: $EmployeeID"
Write-Host "Forenames: $Forenames"
Write-Host "Surname: $Surname"
Write-Host $File


$SQL="SELECT [EMPLOYEEID], [SURNAME] FROM [database].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE] WHERE EMPLOYEEID = '$EmployeeID' AND [SURNAME] = '$Surname'"

        $Verification=Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $SQL -ServerInstance “server.domain.com,42000” -database “db” -Username "user" -Password "pass" -OutVariable sqlResults

        # Success or error?
            if ($Verification -ne $Null)
            {
                Write-Output "Found match of $EmployeeID and $Surname, moving to upload"
                # Verification passed, move source file to upload
                If(!(test-path $finalPath))
                {
                    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $finalPath
                }
                Write-Host "Removing employee name from the filename"
                $finalFileName = $finalPath + $File.Replace($Surname+"^"+$Forenames+"^", "")
                Move-Item $localPath$File $finalFileName
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Output "Verification of $EmployeeID and $Surname failed. Moving to $errorsPath"
                Move-Item $localPath$File $errorsPath
                Send-MailMessage -To $EmailTo -From $EmailFrom -Subject $EmailSubject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Body $EmailBody -Attachments $EmailAttachment
            }

}```
````

Comment: I'm not sure who you employ; however you may want to look out for Bobby Tables... and have a look at [Example 3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#example-3--invoke-a-script-and-pass-in-variable-values-from-a-string) on how to properly do SQL variables

Answer (score 2):

For starters, your loop has data type issues. `$Files` is a collection of FileInfo objects. You didn't show your output but I'd assume it's null or gibberish.

```
#Try replacing 
$File.Split(...)
#with
$File.Name.Split(...)
#or
$File.FullName.Split(...)
```

The properties of the `$File` object contain strings. I think you're assuming that `$File` itself is a string.